# Is it possible to authenticate user to automatically be logged into wp-admin usgin API auth?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-admin

I have made a user authentication functionality on the front-end using WordPress API / JWT and VueJS.

It works fine and user is logged in, you can do whatever you desire using the API. But what I need is for user to actually go to the wp-admin panel to edit a page. At this stage, user is asked to log in again.

Is there any way to authenticate users using WordPress API and also have them logged in to wp-admin so they wouldn't have to log in again?

Comment: users can save their cookies. you can try to find out what cookies wordpress saves and check if you can programatically create them with the api auth tokens

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couldn't find any good way of doing this so I ended up with this solution:

```
var bodyFormData = new FormData();
                bodyFormData.set('log', vm.username);
                bodyFormData.set('pwd', vm.pass);
                axios({
                    method: 'post',
                    url: '/wp-login.php',
                    data: bodyFormData,
                    config: { headers: {'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' }}
                })
```

Basically, when user logs in through the front-end you would send a post request directly to wp-login.php with the same login details and he would be logged in to the admin dashboard as well.

Works great though if anyone has a better solution, please share!